# How to pass file content as argument to app/console?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, unix, doctrine

I'm looking for a way to pass a SQL file as argument of `app/console doctrine:query:sql`...

What I tried:

```
php app/console doctrine:query:sql < myfile.sql
```

and

```
cat myfile.sql | php app/console doctrine:query:sql
```

But nothing worked.

And I found nothing in any documentation about a way of doing that.

Here is the kind of sql file content:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: preprod
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `my_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
...
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of myfile.sql?

Answer (score 1):

```
php app/console doctrine:query:sql "`cat myfile.sql`"
```

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/php: Argument list too long

Comment: apparently it is quite a big file. **IF** you don't have multiline statements, you can try something like `while read sql; do php app/console doctrine:query:sql "$sql"; done < myfile.sql`, but frankly, you'd better go with plain mysql client.

Comment: yes... It's way too long and it cannot parse the first lines of the file... I'll find another way, thanks

Comment: Could be an interesting PR so this command can accept a file path.

Comment: @COil, I would recommend to use http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html instead.

Comment: That's not really the question. You could want to test sql without creating a migration. Depends on what you want to do.